# Trying to build c++20 aplication with modules

Tags: c++, module, c++20, clang++, c++-modules

I am trying use in app precompiled modules from other lib. I am specifies path to lib pcm-files with *-fprebuilt-module-path=* and link *.so file, but recieved the next error:

> fatal error: module '_Builtin_stddef_max_align_t' is defined in both '/home/user/.cache/clang/ModuleCache/1ZQ7RBKO4A6V0/_Builtin_stddef_max_align_t-1KLR31KNJ6263.pcm' and '/home/user/.cache/clang/ModuleCache/1VEVSXT4LZMYX/_Builtin_stddef_max_align_t-1KLR31KNJ6263.pcm'

If I trying clear cache its require rebuild lib because pcm files depend by cache.

If I trying specified non default path to cache its not fixes problem too.

I think I must use some specific compile option to resolve it but I doesnt understand which

Maybe someone's face with it?

P. S. Sorry I didn't found a simple reproducer for this problem

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you (similarly to me) are hitting this Clang bug: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53231

In my case this was caused by a mismatch in preprocessor macros (defines) supplied from the compiler command line at module build- an import times. Also it had something to do with the different kinds of internal module mechanisms within Clang clashing.

I was able to get around this by figuring out which macros were different in the different compiler invocations, and telling Clang to ignore them (at least with regard to module integrity/caching), using the `-fmodules-ignore-macro=FOOBAR` argument.

**EDIT**: I appear to have had a significant misunderstanding, that in addition to `-std=c++20`, Clang also requires `-fmodules` to actually provide module functionality. In fact it does not, and `-fmodules` enables an additonal, older, Clang-specific module system, which clashes with the standard C++ module system already enabled by `-std=c++20`. So in my case, simply removing the `-fmodules` compiler argument also fixed the error.

Comment: Attila, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Alright, I've added a bit more detail right here.